# jQuery: Redirect user if urls equals not

Tags: jquery, redirect

I want to redirect user to a specific page, when they are not on this page.

So something like (pseudo code):

```
if not (url = example.com/index.php)
   redirect to example.com/index.php
/if
```

When a user e.g. visit page example.com/forum.php he will be redirected to example.com/index.php

(The jQuery file is loaded in every file)

How can I archive that?

Comment: Check window.location... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href`. Example here...

```
if(url === 'example.com/forum.php'){
    window.location.href = 'example.com/index.php';
    return False;
}
```

Don't forget to use `return false` at the end of the block so that if there are any runnable code after the `window.location.href`, then browser can ignore that

Comment: Yes that works, but I figured out, that the url === does not work for me: Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate further, since I cannot comment...url will return undefined without first defining it (you will notice Zoker's comment above).

To define `url`, you can do this:

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
```

Then you can proceed to perform the check:

```
if(url === 'yourspecifiedurl.com'){
     window.location.href = 'yournewurl.com';
     return false;
}
```

Additionally, you do not need to use `window.location.href` 
as window.location will suffice. It defaults to `window.location.href`

A final thought, you can also use replace:

```
window.location.replace('theurltodirectto.com');
```